# Powershell start executable that requires to type "Y"

Tags: powershell

In a powershell script, I have to run an external command.

This command is a command line executable that requires to confirm its execution by typing `Y` (
`Do you want to proceed?
[Y or N] then press [enter]`).

Unfortunately, there's no silent switch.

How can I run the command, wait for this confirmation and type `Y` in place of the user?

I tried:

```
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$psi.FileName = "\\path\to\my\executable.exe"
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false
$psi.RedirectStandardInput = $true
$psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$psi.Arguments = '-import -scope "\\path\to\my\scope.xml"'


$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)

$line = ""
do{
    while($line = $p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()){
        Write-Host $line

        if($line -Eq "[Y or N] then press [enter]:"){
            $p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y")
        }
    }
} while(-not $p.HasExited)
```

But it looks like the process exit immediately. The output is only the first line of my command.

I should be actually :

```
Search Migration Tool v1.2.1
Program Action: Import
SharePoint objects considered: Scopes
Conflict Behavior: Continue
Filename: \\path\to\my\scope.xml

Do you want to proceed?
[Y or N] then press [enter]:
```

But only `Search Migration Tool v1.2.1` is displayed

Comment: Did you try: `'Y'|&"\\path\to\my\executable.exe"`?

Comment: @PetSerAl: it works! you should write this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases you does not have to wait `Do you want to proceed?` request. You just write something in application's input stream, and application pick it up, when application will need it. In simplest case, you just pipe something to application, and it got written to application's input stream, so you does not even have to bother with `Process` class directly:

```
'Y'|&"\\path\to\my\executable.exe"
```

Comment: A perfect example of a very simple solution, while I was drowning in a complex solution. Thanks